# Fetch where timestamp field value is less then last day mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with timestamp field and I want to fetch all the data where timestamp value is less then last day. I tried following code but its not working and giving me blank array.

```
$start = strtotime(date('2016-01-26'));    
$qry = "SELECT * FROM kom_payment_logs WHERE date<".$start;
$query = db_query($qry);
```

How can I use php date function value in where condition for timestamp field.

Comment: Your query says that you want all dates that's after `$start` (2016-01-26). Don't you mean `WHERE date <" . $start`? Or do you have log files for tomorrow? :o

Comment: `$qry = "SELECT * FROM kom_payment_logs WHERE date>'2016-01-26'";`

Comment: just updated the ques

Comment: Ok. Does that mean that this isn't the actual code you have issues with? You should copy/paste the actual code. Then we can see if there are any mistakes in it. Hard to debug psuedo-code. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check whether your mysql date field is itself a timestamp field.
Secondly, get value of $start in php, put it in place of $start in mysql query and run the query directly from phpmyadmin > mysql table > sql and see if any error is shown after executing the query.